# Getting Task list from Microsoft Graph with app-only scopes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve task lists using the Microsoft Graph API (http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/beta/api/task_list) in a service app?

I can successfully request a token that has all of the following scopes:

- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Contacts.Read
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- Directory.Read
- List item
- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- email
- Files.Read
- Files.Read.Selected
- Group.Read.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- Mail.Read
- Mail.Send
- Notes.Create
- Notes.Read
- Notes.Read.All
- Notes.ReadWrite.All
- offline_access
- openid
- People.Read
- profile
- Sites.Read.All
- Tasks.ReadWrite
- User.Read
- User.Read.All
- User.ReadBasic.All
- User.ReadWrite
- User.ReadWrite.All
- user_impersonation

I am able to get lists of users, groups, applications and other entities, but my requests to the `tasks` or `plans` endpoints return the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d0d7d970-ff88-4af9-93d3-8b8d4acfabf0",
      "date": "2016-01-28T12:46:31"
    }
  }
}
```

My expectation is that `Group.ReadWrite.All` is inherited as app-only from `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, so together with `Task.ReadWrite` I should be able to see tasks and plans.

Is there another required permission or another setting that we’ve missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieval of tasks/plans is currently not supported in service-only (app-only) context. Please use user delegation context (app+user) instead.